# How to resize png image with alpha canal in boost::gil

Tags: c++, boost, png, image-resizing, boost-gil

How to resize png image with alpha canal in boost::gil?

```
boost::gil::rgb8_image_t image;
boost::gil::rgb8_image_t newSize(640, 480);
boost::gil::png_read_and_convert_image("input.png",image);
boost::gil::resize_view(const_view(image), view(newSize), boost::gil::bilinear_sampler());
boost::gil::png_write_view("output.png",const_view(newSize));
```

Comment: Is this a question or the answer? If it's question, what is the question? That code not working? Is it? Why not? etc.

Comment: Besides, `resize_view` is not in boost. What are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with resizing but with loading the original PNG in the first place, because `boost::gil::rgb8_image_t` is an image type without an alpha channel.

The solution is to simply use `boost::gil::rgba8_image_t`, which includes an alpha channel.